# VoipSwitch video call issue

Tags: iphone, sip, voip

I am using idoubs application to connect with my VoipSwitch sip server. Audio call is working but when i try to connect with video call its not established and terminate with Transport error.

I checked on VoipSwitch that video codec H263, H263+ are enabled as well as in iphone too.

Please help!
Thanks.

Comment: we will need the SIP Message exchange to begin to understand what goes on.

Comment: This isn't a programming question...